# The api method 'getUi' is only available in the new version of Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I keep getting the above error message after using code supplied by Google for creating custom menus in Google Docs. The code can be found under the top heading titled "Custom menus in Google Docs, Sheets, or Forms" at the following [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus). The left hand side of the column says that the code is for "Google Docs, Forms, or new Sheets," but it doesn't work in Google Docs.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.
Got error: API-method 'getUi' is only available in new version of Google Spreadsheets.

In a document be sure to use DocumentApp everywhere.
Also in the addSubMenu.

Try this:

```
function onOpen() {
   DocumentApp.getUi()


.createMenu('My Menu')
   .addItem('My Menu Item', 'myFunction')
   .addSeparator()
   .addSubMenu(DocumentApp.getUi().createMenu('My Submenu')
       .addItem('One Submenu Item', 'mySecondFunction')
       .addItem('Another Submenu Item', 'myThirdFunction'))
   .addToUi();
 }
```